# iOS: Detect screen rotation, but prevent it from actually happening?

Tags: ios, mobile, uiview

Is there a way to detect that the screen is about to rotate, but also prevent such a rotation from happening?  Essentially, I am trying to implement an interface like the built in camera app in which control objects rotate in place when the device is moved from portrait to landscape (and vice versa), but the layout of the subviews does not actually change.

I can get notices about device orientation changes with:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:)
    name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
    object:nil];
```

and I can prevent rotations altogether by making portrait the only supported orientation, but if I do that, the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification won't fire at all.

Is there a way for me to get my cake and eat it too?

Thanks,

A. Stew Dent

Answer (score 0):

You can still make your application support just Portrait, preventing from rotating, and catch the rotation action with the accelerometer.

Here's some code to perform this:

header file:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, assign) UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation;

@end
```

In implementation file:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration*)acceleration;
{
    CGFloat x = -[acceleration x];
    CGFloat y = [acceleration y];
    CGFloat angle = atan2(y, x);

    if ( angle >= -2.25f && angle <= -0.25f )
    {
        self.interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
    else if ( angle >= -1.75f && angle <= 0.75f )
    {
        self.interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }
    else if( angle >= 0.75f && angle <= 2.25f )
    {
        self.interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
    }
    else if ( angle <= -2.25f || angle >= 2.25f )
    {
        self.interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    }
}
```

Just remember to cancel the accelerometer somewhere, like in your viewWillDisappear:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:nil];

}
```

Please, give some feedback if worked or not.